# AngularJS Test Example

Tags: unit-testing, testing, angularjs

I don't know why but I'm finding it really difficult to get my head around setting up a JavaScript test using AngularJS.

I have my app.js, controller.js plus a number of other files for Ajax, Storage services, filters etc. My app works fine but I want to learn how to do E2E and unit testing.

I think I need to create a standalone HTML page that runs my tests, but I'm not sure, I'm also not sure which extra JavaScript files/libraries I might need.

Is there an AngularJS test example I could use to get the initial set-up?

*Ideally I'd like to run the JS tests I create from within Visual Studio 2012...but that's a nice to have!*

Comment: You can run angularJS unit tests from VS2012 with chutzpah but I don't think you can use it to run e2e tests.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I recomend you to look at angular-seed project.
It has e2e test already setup.
https://github.com/angular/angular-seed

Answer (score 17):

I find this tutorial a good start.

http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/01/full-spectrum-testing-with-angularjs-and-testacular.html

It not only teaches how to do unit testing but also E2E and a special one ...Midway testing. A good reference IMHO.

Answer (score 8):

AngularJS dev guide has a complete page on the subject:
http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing

There is also a blog post mentioning a sample app in github including Testacular tests here:
http://blog.angularjs.org/2012/11/angularjs-example-applications.html

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

[Angular Test Patterns](https://github.com/daniellmb/angular-test-patterns) is worth looking into as well. There are examples in both CoffeeScript and JavaScript for testing [Controllers](https://github.com/daniellmb/angular-test-patterns/blob/master/patterns/controller.md), [Services](https://github.com/daniellmb/angular-test-patterns/blob/master/patterns/service.md), [Directives](https://github.com/daniellmb/angular-test-patterns/blob/master/patterns/directive.md) and [Filters](https://github.com/daniellmb/angular-test-patterns/blob/master/patterns/filter.md). As well as ideas on how to use [Mocks](https://github.com/daniellmb/angular-test-patterns/blob/master/patterns/mock.md), [End-to-End tests](https://github.com/daniellmb/angular-test-patterns/blob/master/patterns/e2e.md) etc.